# IE.Visible = false; But it actually shows ? c#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, navigation, shdocvw

I am trying to navigate ie invisibly, tried this

```
SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
IE.Visible = false;
IE.Navigate("http://example.org");
```

Works, however, it actually shows the IE window. What is the best approach to hide the IE window ?

Comment: May I ask, does your program architecture require IE specifically? If not you could use a webbrowser control to navigate silently. If the only purpose you are trying to achieve for example was to send an HTTP request with the IE user-agent-string  to cache a particular website or some such. You could use the web browser control instead.

Answer (score 3):

From the docs :
"When the Windows Internet Explorer application is first created, it is hidden. It becomes visible after the Navigate method or the GoSearch method is used."

Set Visible AFTER navigating.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752082(v=vs.85).aspx

http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?512303-SHDocVw-InternetExplorerClass-visible-property-to-False-does-not-work-on-some-machine
It seems that the NavigateComplete event also makes the window visible, so it should also be hidden in a handler for that event as well.

Comment: Note the comment at the bottom of the link - that may be the issue.

Comment: See this link that may help http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?512303-SHDocVw-InternetExplorerClass-visible-property-to-False-does-not-work-on-some-machine. You may need to hide it in the NavigateComplete event.

Comment: Still not worked, tried all. Maybe in Win8, Microsoft decided to show always on navigate function. The only thing that worked is to add -embedded command to iexplore.exe (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) It opens hiddenly, but that way I cant achieve what I want. So is there anyway to tell c# to run iexplore.exe -embedded when using navigate ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim IDC As Object
Dim IDCWin As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set IDC = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

For Each IDCWin In IDC.Windows

    If IDCWin.LocationURL = "YOUR WEBSITE" Then 
        IDCWin.Visible = False

Next IDCWin
```

This is what I use and it works for me. I loop through the IE windows and when it locates the specified URL, it then hides that instance of IE. I use it for a web application that I manipulate through excel but I don't want to be visible to the user during use. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try InternetExplorer**Medium** ?? This changes the integrity/security of that IE instance.

```
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set ie = New InternetExplorer**Medium**
ie.Visible = False
```

I run it with `_Medium`, and it is hidden all the time w/o anything other necessary.
Today I dealt with one system on which the `_Medium` has to be omitted to have my code run at all, and when I get it back to debug I have the same issue where it seemingly disregards the `.Visible = False` unless it is _Medium.

Answer (score 0):

hi I had the same issue with VBA in excel and to solve it I had to change back from internetexplorermedium to internetexplorer